# Show bootstrap modal link in browser search

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm using bootstrap cards with href tags, so users can click on them and open bootstrap modals. I want them to be able top copy the modal's url link, so they can share it. The problem is if I open the modal, the url doesn't change. How can I change it?
For example I have this site:

```
example.com/index.php
```

when someone clicks on a card, I'd like to show him this:

```
example.com/index.php#modal-1
```

This is my href link:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
<div class="card">...</div>
</a>
```

and the modal:

```
 <div class="modal full" id="modal-<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="detailsModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">...</div>
```

Edit: I use bootstrap 4

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that. I'm using Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can toggle the modal with the hash.

If your user visits example.com/index.php#modal-1 and you have the snippet below on your site then the modal will open after the document has loaded.

Docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#modaltoggle

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var hash = window.location.hash; // #modal-1
  $(hash).modal('toggle');
});
```

If you want to update the URL in the address bar, you can use a bootstrap custom event to trigger this. Use the .modal class in general and the get the id for the modal from the event object.

Docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', ".modal", function(event) {
  window.location.hash = event.currentTarget.id;
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand this. It doesn't show anything in the url bar.

Comment: The second example is exactly what I'm looking for. Only one question. Is it possible to always replace the '#modal-1' with the right id? The ids come from the database, but I don't really want to place php in the javascript if it's not necessary.

Comment: Good point, answer updated to make the snippet work with multiple ids/models but you we still need to add the IDs to be fair.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly. Exactly what I needed.